# SSIS integration with SVN

Tags: sql-server, svn, ssis

I would like to know about how to integrate and maintain version of `SSIS packages/project` using SVN? By default, there is no versioning support in SSIS. There are tools like `visual svn` which I'm aware of.

Still would like to know something related to below mentioned scenario:

**Scenario:**
To be specific, in `Talend Data Integration` multiple people can work on 1 project at same time. A `job` getting modified by Developer1 is only available to Developer2 in 'Read only' mode.

Similarly, I want to implement in SSIS, where a `package` is accessible to developer2 in 'Read only' mode if developer1 is working on it.

Thanks

Comment: `package is accessible to developer2 in 'Read only' mode if developer1 is working on it.` For multiple devs and version control I suggest [BIML](https://www.varigence.com/Products/Biml/Capabilities) and [BIML example](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/developing-metadata-design-patterns-biml/) (much easier to apply same patterns or compare/merge code).

Comment: Why do you want the read only thing? What's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Thanks. I'm looking into TFS and GitLab as of now to work with.

Comment: @ppijnenburg: So that 2 developers cannot work on a same package at a time. This would cause conflict while committing code. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

**AnhkSVN** (tortoise) is an visual studio integration. It doesn't support the 'open in read only mode when already open' but I think your goal is *"don't overwrite each others code without knowing"* which it provides by simply using check-in and check-out

- [AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

If code has been modified it will cause a conflict which has to be resolved.